# Why is the answer "abcbcc"?

Tags: c

> The output of the following program is _________
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
> int main()
> { 
>   char ch[]="abc",x[3][4]; 
>   int i;
>   for(i=0;i<3;i++) 
>       strcpy(x[i],ch);
>   for(i=0;i<3;i++) 
>       printf("%s",&x[i][i]);
>   printf("\n");
> }
> ```

The answer is `abcbcc`, but I think the answer should be `abc`.
`strcpy()` is used to copy the following to the previous, so the second row of abc is also the third row of abc in the first row array.

```
a b c
a b c
a b c
```

Then output diagonal.

Another puzzle: Why is there a  `&` in `printf("%s",&x[i][i])`?
I thought it would be `printf("%s",x[i][i])`.

Comment: `but in my opinion,I think the answer is abc.` Its not, because: `I think it should be printf("%s",x[i][i])` You're printing strings, not chars. On your first iteration you're printing `abc`, on the second iteration `bc` and on the third iteration `c`.

Comment: `%s` is used to print a zero terminated string. `&x[i][i]` is a pointer to the beginning of the string to print. If you used `printf("%s",x[i][i])` you would have undefined behavior because that argument is not a pointer. `%c` would work for that because it expects a character, and that output would be `abc`.

Comment: The loop that prints the result prints three strings concatenated together.  The first begins at `&x[0][0]`, the second begins at `&x[1][1]`, and the third begins at `&x[2][2]`.  So the first is `abc`, the second is `bc`, and the third is `c`.  Put them together and you get `abcbcc`, just as you'd expect.

Comment: The `strcpy`s are irrelevant, and your program is equivalent to `for (int i=0; i<3; i++) printf("%s", "abc" + i); printf("\n");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The answer is abcbcc, but I think the answer should be abc.

The answer is correct.

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++) 
      printf("%s",&x[i][i]);
  printf("\n");
```

On the first iteration, the value of `i` is 0.
So the call of `printf()` is:

```
printf("%s",&x[0][0]);
```

which prints `abc`.

`i` is then incremented, and the second iteration prints `bc`, and the third then prints `c`.

And because you didn't print a newline, the output of all 3 iterations was concatenated.

---

> Why is there a & in printf("%s",&x[i][i])? I thought it would be
> printf("%s",x[i][i]).

Because the `%s` format specifier expects a null-terminated string. And `x[i][i]` evaluates to a `char`. Mismatching the types and their format specifiers will lead to undefined behaviour.